# Make crud without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, crud

Hello I know how to make real time crud operations without page reload with jquery and php, can I make crud operations without page reload with javascript and php in 2022? If I can how can I?

Comment: jQuery is Javascript so presumably you mean without some of the native methods jQuery gives you. The `Fetch` api seems the most appropriate to accomplish the stated goal

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: And can I send form data to php file without refresh page with fetch?

Comment: jQuery's `$.ajax` is just an abstraction around the browsers native way of making ajax requests. Just google "ajax request native javascript" and you'll find many many many examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, and I think you can use background app refresh instead of using socket programming. It is much easier and faster!

Comment: I can not make without socket?

Comment: You can, it depends on your decision,

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer